# Perform cut on thermal printer

Tags: thermal-printer, escpos

I want to perform a cut with  a thermal printer Custom TG2460-H, by using esc commands.

According with the documentation, command for *total cut and automatic paper moving back* is **0x1c 0xc0 0x34**. However, if I send this commands after the lines to be printed, it does nothing. Command for total cut (without paper moving back, command 0x1B 0x69) works fine, but sometimes (not always) it cut the paper before the end of the printed, and I don't know why. I tried to put some blank lines at the end, but this makes the ticket very long when printer automatically move the paper to perform the cut.

Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this? Struggling with exact same printer and issue right now.

Comment: No, I haven't. I did not finish the project in the end. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the documentation for that printer, but it's likely that a note similar to the one below.
[GS V](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=87)

> Select cut mode and cut paper
> [Notes for all ]
>
> - When Standard mode is selected, these commands are enabled only when processed at the beginning of line.

This command should be sent at the beginning of a line with no print data specified, similar to the question situation.
If there is such a description, create the command accordingly.

---

On the other hand, the above command has a parameter that feeds the paper before cutting and returns the paper after cutting, and the number of units to feed the paper can be specified.
If your printer has that capability, please try use it.

> <Function D> Feeds paper to [cutting position + (n × vertical motion unit)] and executes paper cut, then moves paper to the print start position by reverse feeding.

---

If your printer doesn't have that capability, try the following as a command to print the remaining data in the printer's buffer and move it to the beginning of the line:
[ESC J](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=15)

> Print and feed paper
>
> Prints the data in the print buffer and feeds the paper [n × (vertical or horizontal motion unit)].

If you specify 0 as the number of units to feed parameter, it will be shorter than the simple line feed command by the space between lines (about 6 dots).